# Change user space memory protection flags from kernel module

Tags: memory-management, process, linux-kernel, mmap

I am writing a kernel module that has access to a particular process's memory. I have done an anonymous mapping on some of the user space memory with `do_mmap()`:

```
#define MAP_FLAGS   (MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED | MAP_ANONYMOUS)

prot = PROT_WRITE;
retval = do_mmap(NULL, vaddr, vsize, prot, MAP_FLAGS, 0);
```

`vaddr` and `vsize` are set earlier, and the call succeeds. After I write to that memory block from the kernel module (via `copy_to_user`), I want to remove the `PROT_WRITE` permission on it (like I would with `mprotect` in normal user space). I can't seem to find a function that will allow this.

I attempted unmapping the region and remapping it with the correct protections, but that zeroes out the memory block, erasing all the data I just wrote; setting `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` might fix that, but, from the man pages:

> MAP_UNINITIALIZED (since Linux 2.6.33)
>
> Don't clear anonymous pages. This flag is intended to improve performance on embedded 
>   devices. This flag is only honored if the kernel was configured with the 
>   CONFIG_MMAP_ALLOW_UNINITIALIZED option. Because of the security implications, that option 
>   is normally enabled only on embedded devices (i.e., devices where one has complete 
>   control of the contents of user memory).

so, while that might do what I want, it wouldn't be very portable. Is there a standard way to accomplish what I've suggested?

Comment: Why oh why are you doing all that in your kernel module? With a sanely defined API there's no reason that couldn't be done by the userspace process itself.

Comment: @mpe The reason I can't do it in user space is that the module I'm writing is a process loader; I don't have any influence over the user space code.

Comment: What do you mean by process loader? Do you mean a binfmt handler?

Comment: @mpe Yes, it's a binfmt handler.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't do the loading in userspace and use binfmt_misc to make it appear that the kernel is directly loading your program? (see Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt)

Comment: @mpe I looked at `binfmt_misc` but have had problems with my executable wanting to be loaded at an address already occupied by the interpreter. The default base address for Windows PE executables is `0x400000`, but trying to load to that address in userspace with `mmap` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, I found a function called `get_user_pages()` (best documentation I've found is [here](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-3)) that returns a list of pages from userspace at a given address that can be mapped to kernel space with `kmap()` and written to that way (in my case, using `kernel_read()`). This can be used as a replacement for `copy_to_user()` because it allows forcing write permissions on the pages retrieved. The only drawback is that you have to write page by page, instead of all in one go, but it does solve the problem I described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

In userspace there is a system call `mprotect` that can modify the protection flags on existing mapping. You probably need to follow from the implementation of that system call, or maybe simply call it directly from your code. See `mm/protect.c`.